# Magento uploaded images and 777 permissions

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, image-upload, permissions

When I upload images from Magento 1.9 products page, they get permissions 777. I also found a few other 777 folders, such as `media/catalog/product` folders, and cached images.

Also `var/cache` folders are created with 777, files inside are 600.

I've run the following to make all my folders 644 and all the files 755:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

After the above, I still get new uploaded images with 777 permissions.

Any ideas?

- Update #1: Checked `Mage_Cache_Backend_File`, files are set on 644 and folders on 755.
- Update #2: Checked umask, was 022, also added it to `~/.bashrc`, no change.
- Update #3: changed `umask(0)` to `umask(022)` in index.php.

When I upload a new image, i.e. demo.jpg, then the first folder gets created with 755 params:

```
media/catalog/product/d 755
media/catalog/product/d/e 777
media/catalog/product/d/e/demo.jpg 777
```

Edit:

As Fiasco Labs proposed, I searched with Notepad++ inside files for 0777 entries and changed them to 0644 or 0755 depending if files/folders.

It resulted as the **first folder created to be 755** and the **second folder to 777**, but the files inside are now `644`. So, issue is almost solved, need to dig a bit more.

So I re-set the permissions from time to time just to be sure it's OK.

Comment: Probably find it's hardcoded within Magento somewhere. Since Magento must run on many different server setups, a portion which do not run the http server user/group as the ssh/sftp user/group, the files are being created as 777 so that they are accessible by everyone. You'll need to hunt the code down and create a module that creates the files with your desired permissions. This is why the media/ folder .htaccess shuts off php/cgi execution out of the folder as certain Magento operations allow frontend users to upload files which would leave a massive security hole.

Answer (score 1):

You can download **magentocleanup.php** and run the file to set the correct Files/Folder permission.

Comment: I got the permissions 777/644 by the above command I quoted, my issue is that after that, I still get 777 permissions on new files. Will that php you're saying fix that issue? Either way, I got it from here and I get Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted errors. https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php

Comment: yes its a common file to set the file / folder permission to the proper magento.